# What's a simple but non-trivial example of class defined using union in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

What's a simple but non-trivial example of class defined using union in C++?

- the class should be defined using `union`
- the class should have constructor(s) and destructor explicitly declared and implemented
- the class should have methods that demonstrate the difference of such a class from a class defined using `class` key word

Comment: Is this homework or an interview question? Definitely seems that way from the way the question is poised.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?  You've described what you want, but what is stopping you from writing it?

Comment: Stroustrup's The C++ Programming Language says:

"A class with a constructor, destructor, or copy operation cannot be the type of a *union* member because the compiler would not know which member to destroy."

Comment: @TatianaRacheva: Stroustrup is so very last decade...

Comment: @LaceySnr  It is not a homework neither an interview question. It is a question that I came up while reading some C++ text about classes. It seems to me that  while both `union` and `class` keywords can be used to define classes,  `union` should be actually "useful" in some use cases. But I was challenged to think of such examples.

Comment: @KerrekSB, heh maybe I should stop reading it, then. I was told by my manager it's the bible etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
#include <new>

enum EActive { ActiveNone, ActiveS, ActiveT };
struct S;
struct T;

union Foo
{
   struct TagOnly { EActive current; TagOnly() : current(ActiveNone) { } } tag;
   S a;
   T b;

   void destroy()
   {
     if      (tag.current == ActiveT) b.~T();
     else if (tag.current == ActiveS) a.~S();
   }

   void setS(S const & s)
   {
     destroy();
     S * const p = ::new (static_cast<void*>(&a)) S(s);
     tag.current = p ? ActiveS : ActiveNone;
   }

   // similar for setT(T const & t)

   ~Foo() { destroy(); }

   Foo() : tag() { }

};
```

I'm assuming here that `TagOnly`, `S` and `T` share the common initial segment `EActive`. (It might be smarter to stick `S` and `T` into wrapper classes `<typename U> struct UnionWrapper { EActive tag; U u; /* ...*/ };`.)

Comment: `tag` is not set before reading

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yeah.... assume it is :-)

Comment: Is there some complication preventing a simple constructor?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Life-crushing laziness on my part! It's all folded into the `// ...` line now.

Comment: So basically, you're saying that S will have its EActive set to S, and T to T, somehow?

Comment: @TatianaRacheva: It's just the usual "tagged union" thingamajig that you're already familiar with, and not specific to C++. I'm just using the member functions here to implement it, but you're free to use your imagination.

Comment: Also, can you explain what ::new (&a) S(s); does? That line doesn't compile for me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "tagged unions."

Comment: Also, doesn't this mean that you can't set Foo directly, you have to use setS and setT?

Comment: Finally, this doesn't exactly answer the question of why you'd want to use this technique. Is there a plausible example?

Comment: @TatianaRacheva: I've corrected and embellished the example a bit, I hope it makes sense now. Explaining a tagged union would be a separate question; you can either post one, or see if you can find some info on the internet. Basically, you always store a "tag" at the top of the union to tell you which member is active.

Comment: @TatianaRacheva: Sorry, the placement-new requires the inclusion of the `<new>` header; I omitted that from my original example. It's now added for completeness.

Comment: One usually makes a *union-like class* which is a structure with a tag member and an anonymous union containing the variant members.  That pre-empts the whole "do all member types start with a common sequence" problem.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That might work in C with external manipulator functions, but how would this translate into C++ with self-contained member functions? As I said, I'd rather have an abstract tagging wrapper for the payload members... or you'd have a large wrapper class around the union. There are no anonymous unions, by thhe way.

Comment: @KerrekSB, cool, I'll try this when I get back to it. See, this is a good question :) At least I learned 3 or 4 things already.

Comment: @TatianaRacheva: Learning something is always good :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: The special member functions go in the *union-like class*, not the union itself.